# Prevent dropdown menu to be shown automatically

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to prevent dropdown menu to be shown automatically when I remove 'hidden' class in jQuery :

**html:**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs friend-request tooltiped" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add as friend" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-friend-single-btn no-friend-sent dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-profile-id="1">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Friend 
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu hidden">
    <li class="cancel-friend-request" data-profile-id="1">
      <a href="#">Cancel</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
  $('body').on('click', '.add-friend-single-btn', function() {

    //Send friend request
    if($(this).hasClass('no-friend-sent')){
      var obj = $(this);
      var to_user_id = obj.attr('data-profile-id');

      obj.css('background', '#d24d33');
      obj.html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Pending <span class="caret"></span>');
      obj.addClass('is-pending-friend-request');
      obj.removeClass('no-friend-sent');

      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul').removeClass('hidden');
    }

  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eaad0a44/

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/eaad0a44/1/ , if not please explain what should happend

Comment: When I click on friend button I want remove the hidden class in dropdown menu but I don't want show it

Comment: I want show the dropdown menu only on click event, after hidden class is removed

Comment: the jsfidde you share is what you want to achieve?? we are not really clear about your question

Comment: no, there is a problem in my jsfiddle.....
When I click on 'friend' button I want remove the 'hidden' class in dropdown menu but I don't want show it automatically. Show the dropdown menu only when I click on the 'Pending' button

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you need this. Try this.

```
  $('body').on('click', '.add-friend-single-btn', function(event) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('no-friend-sent')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    //Send friend request
    if ($(this).hasClass('no-friend-sent')) {

      var obj = $(this);
      var to_user_id = obj.attr('data-profile-id');

      obj.css('background', '#d24d33');
      obj.html('<i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Pending <span class="caret"></span>');
      obj.addClass('is-pending-friend-request');
      obj.removeClass('no-friend-sent');
      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul').removeClass('hidden');
    }

  });
```